# In django, can one use F() objects to see if a constant contains strings from a field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

All,
   I'm trying to basically do keyword notifications, so whenever an object with a name is created, anyone who wants to be notified of any of the words in this name will be. 
e.g.

```
Records:
   keyword: Hello
   keyword: World

New Name: "Hello World"

Returns both records
```

I've created a query that correctly works for this in sqlite, and I know how to translate it across databases.

```
SELECT * FROM table t
WHERE "a constant string" LIKE "%" || t.field || "%";
```

I've determined that within django, one can use [F() objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) to compare one field to another field, like so:

```
Entry.objects.filter(n_comments__gt=F('n_pingbacks'))
```

Now anyone know how to replace the first field with a constant string?  Like so:

```
Entry.objects.filter("constant string"__icontains=F('n_pingbacks'))
```

Or am  I going about this backwards?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not try to fight with django ORM. It covers the most often things but your case is not the one. Just use `extra` to get what you need (or even `raw`).

Comment: darn, I was afraid of that.  I really didn't want to have to write this in `raw` because the concat is database specific.

Comment: well, that's why this feature is not in ORM :) it's too specific and database dependent while django provides support for several dbs.

Comment: Please provide an example to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look particularly pretty but it can be done all with standard filters.

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, CharField, Value

Entry.objects.annotate(
    my_const=ExpressionWrapper(Value("a constant string"),
                               output_field=CharField())
).filter(my_const__contains=F('n_pingbacks'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by providing a `dict` of arguments, e.g.:

```
Entry.objects.filter(**{("%s__icontains" % constant_string):F('n_pingbacks')})
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, unless the constant_string is the name of a field.  As I want to search an arbitrary string, not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using '.extra' to select your const as field, than using myconst__contains, like:

```
queryset.extra(select={'myconst': "'this superstring is myconst value'"}).filter(myconst__contains=F('myfield'))
```

Do not forget to put constant value in apostrophes inside double qoutation marks.

But, will somebody help me put it into Q object? =)

UPD:
Suddenly, it fails because of the following issue:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13363

Maybe, they will fix it.

UPD: You can filter by fields that added with '.annotate', but I don't know, how to put constant here instead of aggregation. Maybe, with creation of custom aggreation function, like here:
http://coder.cl/2011/09/custom-aggregates-on-django/

UPD: I made custom aggregator, this logic seems to be correct, because the query I got from queryset is quite similar to I wanted it to be, but, unfortunately, there is another issue: 16731 (sorry not providing full url, not enough rep, see another ticket above).

UPD(last): I have managed to do this using monkeypatching of the following:

1. django.db.models.sql.Query.query_terms
2. django.db.models.fields.Field.get_prep_lookup
3. django.db.models.fields.Field.get_db_prep_lookup
4. django.db.models.sql.where.WhereNode.make_atom

Just defined custom lookup 'starts', which has reverse logic of 'startswith'